# WHERE from CASE result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a statement - simplified

```
SELECT UserID,
CASE WHEN UserName = 'xxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS Deleted
FROM User
WHERE Deleted = 0;
```

but this doesn't work because `Deleted` can't be used.

Is there a workaround? I can't solve it this way `WHERE UserName <> 'xxx'` , because in my real statement it's a huge sub select.

Comment: And what is the problem with using WHERE and sub-query?

Comment: If you were wondering why a column alias cannot be referenced in the where clause; it is a consequence of something called the [logical processing order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).  TL/DR: Each clause in your query is executed in a set order.  The output of each clause becomes the input of the next.  The select clause is processed after the where clause.

Comment: @destination-data, this is wrong in so many ways. The whole statement is processed before the execution therefore everything is known in the execution time. Some database, e.g. Teradata support aliases in every part of the SQL statement.

Comment: You're right, my comments only relate to SQL Server.  I should have highlighted that is it called the *logical* processing order for a reason.  The actual execution may/can vary.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):  *The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your original query up in a derived table. (Since column aliases aren't available in the same query's where clause.)

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT UserID,
           CASE WHEN UserName = 'xxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Deleted
    FROM User
) dt
WHERE dt.Deleted = 0;
```

Comment: @Andrew L, is that dt table alias required by SQL Server? According to ANSI SQL it's optional, but I know some products wants it - but I can never remember which ones.

Comment: it's resolved, @jarlh, too much hurry to answer :D.. and not edited after that! but +1 for cool quick reply.

Comment: Yes- in 2008 it is a requirement. Can't speak to the newer versions, though.

Answer (score 0):

We can use like below without sub queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [User]
WHERE (CASE WHEN UserName = 'xxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Comment: Now the `Deleted` field is missing

Comment: Deleted field not required. We can use directly. Why do we need 'Deleted' field ?